# What's the name of a heavy duty square cap plate I can order from home depot to support a temporary lally column on a bottle jack

Tags: structural, metal

I'm thinking of using a 4x4 and a bottle jack to lift a loose joist in my basement and wondering what I should use as a top plate on top of the bottle jack and between the 4x4.  Thinking a small piece of flat strong square metal would do the trick, but not sure what to search for in the home depot website.

Seems like something like this Lally Colum Cap works, but it's not available in any stores near me.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-Lally-Column-Cap-and-Base-Jack-Post-340876/202090322

It doesn't have to have any screw holes or anything, just strong square metal piece that can handle being the bottle jack pressure and spread it out to the 4x4.

Is there a simple term I can search in home depot?  The flat bar metal seems like just long bars that I don't have the means to cut.

Comment: Unless trying to lift the house, probably don't need it.  Main thing is to keep everything in a straight vertical line.  Any thing not straight will tend to kick out.  Just needing to lift a joist little bit should not damage wood that much.

Comment: If you're concerned about denting the joist from the top of the bottle jack, put a sacrificial piece of 2x4 between the two. Let it take the dent & spread the pressure across the bottom of the joist. Of course, that's one more thing that has to be lined up as you're getting things going. Also, there are other retailers that may sell similar items. Don't limit yourself to just one favorite store. (I'll go orange when blue doesn't have what I'm after...)

Comment: I would use a 2x4 scrap also.

Comment: Yes a 2x4 scrap on one joist. Do not brace joists. If concerned about lining many things up and holding them in place while applying pressure, you can tack with a screw into the joist, or into the 4x4.

Comment: Also if you'd like to have a cap plate, from the look of it you could order a 4" square piece of good steel of whatever thickness and drill a few holes in it.  The pressed dents don't look critical to function.